# SSRS (SQL Server Report Service) Subscription mails are not getting sent from the Data Base (Report Server) After upgrading to SendGrid API Keys

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, sendgrid, reportingservices-2005, sendgrid-api-v3

SSRS (SQL Server Report Service) Subscription mails are not getting sent from the Data Base (Report Server).

Recently we have updated the SendGrid API Keys to send emails (before it was UserName and Password).

After rolling out API Keys, we are facing SQL Server Reporting Service Email Subscriptions are getting failed.

(do we need to configure anything in the SQL Server Reporting Service Cofig file.?

please let us know if you encountered any same issues.

### Find the Below Error in Report Server Logs.

brary!WindowsService_27!1e44!01/14/2021-08:07:15:: i INFO: Initializing StoredParametersThreshold to '1500' characters as specified in Server system properties.
emailextension!WindowsService_27!1e44!01/14/2021-08:07:15:: e ERROR: Error sending email. Exception: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed.
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 read, Boolean readLine)
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ReadLines(SmtpReplyReader caller, Boolean oneLine)
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ReadLine(SmtpReplyReader caller)
at System.Net.Mail.CheckCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, String& response)
at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, Byte[] command, MailAddress from, Boolean allowUnicode)
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, Boolean allowUnicode, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception)
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
at Microsoft.ReportingServices.EmailDeliveryProvider.EmailProvider.Deliver(Notification notification)
notification!WindowsService_27!1e44!01/14/2021-08:07:15:: e ERROR: Error occurred processing subscription b0ef6472-f255-48ed-bb1d-79a813ee4d64: Failure sending mail: Failure sending mail.

[Find the Screenshot of ReportConfig file here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPgzJ.png)

Comment: Same issue, did you solve it?

Comment: @KonstantinSalavatov 

Sorry for the late reply, yeah i have solved the issue check in below link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/234781/ssrs-error-error-sending-email-exception-systemnet.html

Comment: Solution:

Here is the solution for our problem:

Very recently SendGrid stopped basic authentication method to send mail (our servers were configured long back).

To fix this issue, we have updated Email Settings in "Reporting Services Configuration Manager".
with
Authentication: UserName and Password (Basic) -> Dropdown.
UserName: apikey
Password: very long WEIRED API Key generated Generated at SendGrid.